# python: row concat 2 dataframes, keeping their names as a new column

Tags: python, r, pandas, rbind

I'm looking for the Pythonic way to do the equivalent as `bind_rows` (**`dplyr`** package in R), that does dataframe concatenation from a list of data.frames and automatically adds the name of each data.frame as an `.id` column to remember where the rows comes from.

Is there a simple way to do this? I tried to use `pd.concat`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2]], columns=['letter', 'number'])
df2 = df1.copy()
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Expected output:

```
####     .id letter  number
#### 0   df1      a       1
#### 1   df1      b       2
#### 0   df2      a       1
#### 1   df2      b       2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `keys`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1', 'df2'],names =['id','index']).reset_index(level=0)
Out[880]: 
        id letter  number
index                    
0      df1      a       1
1      df1      b       2
0      df2      a       1
1      df2      b       2
```

If you want dynamic create the keys

```
pd.concat({x : y for x,y in enumerate([df1, df2])},names =['id','index']).reset_index(level=0)
Out[879]: 
       id letter  number
index                   
0       0      a       1
1       0      b       2
0       1      a       1
1       1      b       2
```

Comment: ok thanks, i just checked this key argument in the doc, not very clear to me, you're using it for its side effect or it is the actual purpose of the argument?

Comment: @agenis just add the id for the data here they come from ,it is more like a side effect

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2],keys=['df1','df2']).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns = {'level_0':'.id'})

    id  letter  number
0   df1 a   1
1   df1 b   2
0   df2 a   1
1   df2 b   2
```

Comment: looks same  with my answer .

Comment: Yes. I saw just now. I read the question and posted the answer. Anyways, I upvoted yours as you posted earlier

Comment: same function, thanks for the "rename' tip at the end that matches my column name